# How can I start a VNC server session and immediately land up in KDE?

Tags: x11, kde, vnc

This is the content of my ~/.vnc/xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
/usr/bin/startkde &
```

My objective is to land up in KDE desktop environment. I start up the vnc session via ssh using the following command:

```
vncserver -geometry 1550x950
```

But I landed up in Gnome desktop. Anything obviously wrong in my configuration?

N.B: I am using Oracle Enterprise Linux 7.

Comment: What's in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`? what's in `/etc/vnc/xstartup` if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

You run

```
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

which tells the system "load `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, and *overwrite* this process by starting that program instead".

In essense, there are two possible outcomes from that:

- `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` cannot be started (because it doesn't exist, or it doesn't have the right permission bits, or whatnot). You get an error message. If you run your scripts with `set -e`, as you should, your script will also exit.
- `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` can be started. Your program ends, and `xinitrc` runs in its stead.

Assuming the former isn't the case, this means that your script is equivalent to:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

...and nothing else.

if you want KDE instead of Gnome, you therefore have two options:

1. drop the `exec` line. This is probably the easier option.
2. Keep the `exec` line (but drop everything beyond it, for clarity), and configure your default X configuration so it starts KDE rather than gnome.

Comment: How do I do this :"configure your default X configuration so it starts KDE rather than gnome."?